# How to answer when asker has done a small thing, and asks how to do a big unrelated thing?

Tags: discussion, questions, needs-more-focus

I sometimes see questions looking like the following:

> I have done [this simple thing]. From there, how do I do [this big thing]?

For example:

> I have done the following HTML form (some code). How do I implement PHP and JavaScript validation [with lag compensation [and animated error-messages]]?

How can I answer this kind of question? Should I?

Comment: Flag/Vote to close => Too broad.

Comment: Why would you *want* to answer such a question?  Nobody has the time or the space to write a book.

Comment: Except authors, though I suspect they are allied with unholy forces to accomplish such feats.

Comment: So a software development Q&A site can, itself, get zapped by its own kind of "scope creep?" :)

Comment: @DavidW: Q&A is the key :P Such "questions" aren't, really.

Comment: Easy :)  -- 1) Learn php. 2) learn Javascript. 3) Write the damn thing.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Whether or not they have done [small thing] is entirely irrelevant. The question is essentially "write my code for me" and should be treated as such (with downvotes and closure).

Comment: Why don't you rather give them pointers instead of shooting them down and being completely unhelpful?  Perhaps there is an easy way to do things that they don't know about.

Comment: What I always do is simply type "What have you tried? Any Fiddle?" and depending on the OP I might add "What is your **exact** problem?"

Comment: @Roman Because the purpose of this site is not to give random, vague pointers to people completely new to a subject, nor to do their whole task for them. It doesn't stem from rudeness or unhelpfulness - such questions are just off-topic, unless the poster is able to formulate their problem according to our rules. If they are polite, they usually still get lots of help in the comments, pointing them in the direction of the core of their issue.

Comment: @Roman how is that unhelpful. The reason for closing the question is to be helpful.

Comment: @Jon. Because if someone for example says "I have created an HTML table" (simple thing).  "How do I create a table with pagination and searching and sort functionality and loads data dynamically" (big thing).  Then instead of closing the question, you may just say "try Jquery Datatables".  And then he knows.  And if that technology didn't exist, then you might say "There is no easy way to do this, but ... will help"

Comment: @Roman, sure, but it's also helpful to close the question.

Answer (score 13):

> how to do a big unrelated thing?

As @Mat said in his comment, it is highly likely to be voted to be closed as "Too broad".

Whether small or big, if OP is not asking a relevant question about the problem he is facing, then it should be voted to be closed. if the implementation part is big, then OP could narrow down to his specific problem and post the relevant details.

The "Too broad" category is self explanatory:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.